# How to avoid N+1 queries with Spring Data REST Projections?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have been prototyping my new application in Spring Data REST backed by Spring Data JPA & Hibernate, which has been a fantastic productivity booster for my team, but as the data model becomes more complex the performance is going down the tubes. Looking at the executed SQL, I see two separate but related problems:

1. When using a `Projection` with only a few properties to reduce the size of my payload, SDR is still loading the entire entity graph, with all the overhead that incurs. **EDIT: filed [DATAREST-1089](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1089)**
2. There seems to be no way to specify eager loading using JPA, as SDR auto-generates the repository methods so I can't add `@EntityGraph` to them. (and per DATAREST-905 below, even that doesn't work) **EDIT: addressed in Cepr0's answer below, though this can only be applied to each finder method once. See [DATAJPA-749](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-749)**

I have one key model that I use several different projections of depending on the context (list page, view page, autocomplete, related item page, etc), so implementing one custom `ResourceProcessor` doesn't seem like a solution.)

Has anyone found a way around these problems? Otherwise anyone with a non-trivial object graph will see performance deteriorate drastically as their model grows.

My research:

- [How do I avoid n+1 queries with Spring Data Rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886897/how-do-i-avoid-n1-queries-with-spring-data-rest) (from 2013)
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-466
  (
  Add support for lazy loading configuration via JPA 2.1 fetch-/loadgraph.)
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-905 (
  No way to avoid loading all child relations in spring-data-rest?) (2016, unanswered)

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1089 - this is what we are waiting for, right?

Comment: [Closed Projection does not work with @EntityGraph](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1814)

Answer (score 4):

To fight with 1+N issue I use the following two approaches:

**@EntityGraph**

I use '@EntityGraph' annotation in Repository for `findAll` method. Just override it:

```java
@Override
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"author", "publisher"})
Page<Book> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

This approach is suitable for all "reading" methods of Repository.

**Cache**

I use **cache** to reduce the impact of 1+N issue for complex Projections.

Suppose we have **Book** entity to store the book data and **Reading** entity to store the information about the number of readings of a specific Book and its reader rating. To get this data we can make a Projection like this:

```java
@Projection(name = "bookRating", types = Book.class)
public interface WithRatings {

    String getTitle();
    String getIsbn();

    @Value("#{@readingRepo.getBookRatings(target)}")
    Ratings getRatings();
}
```

Where `readingRepo.getBookRatings` is the method of ReadingRepository:

```java
@RestResource(exported = false)
@Query("select avg(r.rating) as rating, count(r) as readings from Reading r where r.book = ?1")
Ratings getBookRatings(Book book);
```

It also return a projection that store "rating" info:

```java
@JsonSerialize(as = Ratings.class)
public interface Ratings {

    @JsonProperty("rating")
    Float getRating();

    @JsonProperty("readings")
    Integer getReadings();
}
```

The request of `/books?projection=bookRating` will cause the invocation of `readingRepo.getBookRatings` for every Book which will lead to redundant **N** queries.

To reduce the impact of this we can use the **cache**:

Preparing the cache in the SpringBootApplication class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    //...

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {

        Cache bookRatings = new ConcurrentMapCache("bookRatings");

        SimpleCacheManager manager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        manager.setCaches(Collections.singletonList(bookRatings));

        return manager;
    }
}
```

Then adding a corresponding annotation to `readingRepo.getBookRatings` method:

```java
@Cacheable(value = "bookRatings", key = "#a0.id")
@RestResource(exported = false)
@Query("select avg(r.rating) as rating, count(r) as readings from Reading r where r.book = ?1")
Ratings getBookRatings(Book book);
```

And implementing the cache eviction when Book data is updated:

```java
@RepositoryEventHandler(Reading.class)
public class ReadingEventHandler {

    private final @NonNull CacheManager cacheManager;

    @HandleAfterCreate
    @HandleAfterSave
    @HandleAfterDelete
    public void evictCaches(Reading reading) {
        Book book = reading.getBook();
        cacheManager.getCache("bookRatings").evict(book.getId());
    }
}
```

Now all subsequent requests of `/books?projection=bookRating` will get rating data from our cache and will not cause redundant requests to the database.

More info and working example is [here](https://github.com/Cepr0/projection-cache-demo).